# cxxTestgen.py throw a syntax error

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio, unit-testing

I've follow the tutorial on [cxxtest Visual Studio Integration](http://cxxtest.com/index.php?title=Visual_Studio_integration) and I've looked on google but found nothing.

When I try to lunch a basic test with cxxtest and visual studio I get this error :

```
1>Generating main code for test suite
1>  File "C:/cxxtest/cxxtestgen.py", line 60
1>    print usageString()
1>                    ^
1>SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am at the step 7 of the tutorial and all my setting are set exactly as they are on the tutorial.

this is the basic test script :

```
#include <cxxtest/TestSuite.h>
 class MyTestSuite : public CxxTest::TestSuite 
  {
  public:
      void testAddition( void )
      {
          TS_ASSERT( 1 + 1 > 1 );
          TS_ASSERT_EQUALS( 1 + 1, 2 );
      }
  };
```

Edit : I am using Python 3.0, could it be the problem?

Comment: Heh - yes. You added that while I was working on my answer. See below for a link to the specifics, and install Python 2.6 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be using Python 3.0 on a body of code which is not ready for python 3.0 - your best bet is to downgrade to python 2.6 until cxxtestgen.py works with python 3.0.

See http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function for details

Answer (score 2):

The previous comments correctly note that CxxTest 3.x did not support Python 3.x.  However, CxxTest 4.0 has recently been released, and it supports Python 3.1 and 3.2.

See the CxxTest Home Page: [cxxtest website](http://cxxtest.com)

Comment: There is an extra '.' at the end of the URL :P

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `cxxtestgen.py` on command line. Does it print the usage page?